# How would I be able to retrieve an MSMQ message after a specific time has passed?

Tags: c#, msmq

I have an MSMQ which would be used almost as some form of "Schedule queue" for sending out tweets at specific time (Think of it as setting a time to send a specific tweet out).

I have sort of ran into a brick wall in how I would retrieve items from the queue. I am aware of the `Peek()` and `Remove()` methods, and they work, but they wouldn't remove the item which is next scheduled to be processed, they would simply only retrieve the the oldest item on the queue.

I have also had a look at using the `TimeToBeReceived` property, but it doesn't seem to make much difference.

If I was to add an message to the queue, with the `TimeToBeReceived` property of the next hour, I shouldn't expect to be able to retrieve it for the next hour, it the `RetrieveNextItem()` method I have written should either return nothing at all or the next item where the time has passed. Could anyone explain to me how I would accomplish this?

Please see my code below to get an general idea on what I already have.

```
public void AddItemToQueue(IScheduledTweet scheduledTweet)
{
    MessageQueue messageQueue = new MessageQueue(@".\Private$\TwitterBot");
    Message message = new Message();

    message.Body = scheduledTweet;

    message.TimeToBeReceived = scheduledTweet.Time.TimeOfDay;

    messageQueue.Send(scheduledTweet);
}

public IScheduledTweet RetrieveNextItem()
{
    IScheduledTweet returnValue;
    MessageQueue messageQueue;

    messageQueue = new MessageQueue(@".\Private$\TwitterBot");
    messageQueue.MessageReadPropertyFilter.TimeToBeReceived = true;
    messageQueue.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] { typeof(ScheduledTweet) });

    // I expect the message variable to be a message where its TimeToBeReceived property is either equal to the current time, or past the time.
    Message message = messageQueue.Peek();
    returnValue = (ScheduledTweet)message.Body;

    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: `TimeToBeReceived` doesn't do what you think it does. Read the MSDN documentation for it again.

Comment: @MarcelN. Ah - I think your right. Do you have any idea how I would accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: .. don't use MSMQ for what it's not supposed to do?

Comment: @stuartd What would you recommend I do?

Comment: It is very unusual to want to do this.  If you wait too long then you have a queue that grows without bounds.  And you can't really guess at a "safe" delay since it entirely depends on what the other end is going.  The odds that it delays *exactly* as long are zero, so you'll either wake up and find nothing or always fall behind.  Use a Timer if you don't think it is a bad idea.

Comment: If you want to do things on a schedule, why not use a scheduler? I've used [quartz.net](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) in the past it worked well.